# Php Get Values from url

Tags: php, get

**http://text.com/text/index.php?route=common/response&DR=5Uijhnk+t1j3lFFFEf4RB3zYyX**

I'm trying to get value of **DR** i.e **5Uijhnk+t1j3lFFFEf4RB3zYyX**

So far i've tried,

```
echo $_GET['DR']
```

But it's not printing anything !! Any way to get the value of **DR**

```
var_dump($_GET);
```

giving me below results,

```
array
  'route' => string 'common/response' (length=15)
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($_GET)` return ?

Comment: remove the / from your get

Comment: maybe you can use $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] but it shoudn't be the best way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
    $current_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] 
  // $current_uri = http://text.com/text/index.php?route=common/response&DR=5Uijhnk+t1j3lFFFEf4RB3zYyX

    $parsed_url = parse_url($current_uri);
    print_r($parsed_url);
    /* Array
    (
        [scheme] => http
        [host] => text.com
        [path] => /text/index.php
        [query] => route=common/response&DR=5Uijhnk+t1j3lFFFEf4RB3zYyX
    ) */

   $query = array();
   parse_str($parsed_url['query'], $query); // parse url string

   print_r($query);
   /* Array
    (
      [route] => common/response
      [DR] => 5Uijhnk+t1j3lFFFEf4RB3zYyX
    ) */
```

Answer (score -1):

try wirth Double-quotes & not single quotes

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: sorry, this doesn't make any difference: when a string is used as an array index, it doesn't matter if the string is single or double quoted, a return value or a constant or... the engine just takes the final computation of the string and checks if it is indeed used as a key in the array